# Ruby on Rails migration, change table to MyISAM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How does one create a Rails migration properly so that a table gets changed to MyISAM in MySQL? It is currently InnoDB. Running a raw execute statement will change the table, but it won't update db/schema.rb, so when the table is recreated in a testing environment, it goes back to InnoDB and my fulltext searches fail.

How do I go about changing/adding a migration so that the existing table gets modified to MyISAM and schema.rb gets updated so my db and respective test db get updated accordingly?

Comment: Why don't you want to update schema.rb ?   You can edit your schema.rb and modify the create_table 

create_table(:table, :options => 'ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8')

Comment: Schema.rb will get overwritten, and it won't include the update to make the table to MyISAM.

Comment: Do you want this for just a single table or all tables in the database? If all tables then you could just get `create_table` to default to MyISAM.

Comment: Single table, one that has to have Mysql supported FULLTEXT search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find a great way to do this. You could change your schema.rb like someone suggested and then run: `rake db:schema:load`, however, this will overwrite your data.

The way I did it was (assuming you are trying to convert a table called books):

1. Save the existing data from the CLI:  `CREATE TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM books;`
2. In your new migration file, drop the books table and recreate it with `:options => "ENGINE=MyISAM"` like someone said in the comment
3. Copy the contents back: `INSERT INTO books SELECT * FROM tmp`

Answer (score 3):

i *think* that if you change your schema format (`config.active_record.schema_format`) from :ruby to :sql, all sql will be saved there.

i'd do some tests on a fresh app first if i were you, see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any sql in migrations. This worked for me:

```rb
class ChangeMapOnlyUsersEngine < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    MyModel.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE my_models ENGINE = 'MyISAM';")
  end
end
```

When I did this in the other direction (InnoDB -> MyISAM) it worked fine, without loss of data so I don't think it's neccesary to create temporary tables or similar. Note that MyISAM doesn't support transactions, so any tests against the database for a corresponding ActiveRecord model will be persisted, with a risk of test pollution.