# How to clone the dev database so the tables' engine remains the same

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently when running rake db:test:clone one of the tables should be MyISAM but is instead InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I found is to use:

rake db:test:clone_structure

This will clone the dev database correctly including the engine of the tables. Tested in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just use SQL in your migration:

```
class ChangeStorageEngineOnT < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    execute %Q{
      ALTER TABLE t ENGINE = MYISAM;
    }
  end

  def down
    execute %Q{
      ALTER TABLE t ENGINE = InnoDB;
    }
  end

end
```

Comment: This will indeed make the table use the MyISAM engine but later doing rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test will create the table as InnoDB. schema.rb still doesn't show that the table is MyISAM.

Comment: I think you'll have to drop and re-create the table for it to "stick" in the schema.rb.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923891/ruby-on-rails-migration-change-table-to-myisam

Comment: thanks for the comment. I changed the question to reflect what I really wanted.